# Style ChoiceBox list with CSS in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

[image: list]

How do I access this list in css or in code in order to style it. I couldn't figure it out from modena.css.

By using

```
.choice-box > * {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

the list is unaffected, so it is some kind of separate control.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you with CSS, you will need to also show us your relevant HTML; we can't answer your question without it. Please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated, please post the HTML your back-end **outputs**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I meant [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) kind of css. Sorry, if I shouldn't have used the css tag. There is no HTML.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following selectors should do the coloring in the context menu of the `ChoiceBox`:

```
// Background color of the whole context menu
.choice-box .context-menu { -fx-background-color: black; }
// Focused item background color in the list
.choice-box .menu-item:focused { -fx-background-color: orange; }
// Text color of non-focused items in the list
.choice-box .menu-item > .label { -fx-text-fill: white; }
// Text color of focused item in the list
.choice-box .menu-item:focused > .label { -fx-text-fill: black; }
```

If you color the `ChoiceBox` further:

```
// Background color of the control itself
.choice-box {
  -fx-background-color: black;
  -fx-mark-color: orange; // arrow color
}

// Selected item text color on the control itself
.choice-box > .label { -fx-text-fill: white; }
```

The result will be a `ChoiceBox` like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer:

```
// Selected item mark color
.choice-box .left-container .radio { -fx-background-color: white; }
```